# Issue in running viroBlast from localhost

Tags: javascript, php, blast

I have an issue in running [ViroBlast](https://indra.mullins.microbiol.washington.edu/viroblast/viroblast.php) from my localhost. It is stand-alone BLAST web server that can be installed in your localhost.
When I run it from the above link, the result comes in less than one minutes. But when I run it from my localhost "after install it", it takes "days" showing:

**Your job is being processed**

**Your job id is .......**

**Please wait here to watch the progress of your job.**

**This page will update itself automatically until search is done.**

and nothing happened. 
Could anyone test it please? It just takes few minutes for installing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem. I was running viroBlast for Mac by mistake. I am using Windows.